# How to remove outer array from a nested array?

Tags: ruby

If I have the following `arr = [13,12,31,31]` Now say I want to push in another set of numbers like `12,13,54,32`

So I can do `arr << [12,13,54,32]` but now I have `[13,12,31,31,[12,13,54,32]]`

So how can I remove the outside array? `arr = arr.pop` *works sometimes* but I'm guessing that a better way exists. Please enlighten.

Comment: `arr << [12,13,54,32]` would result in `[13, 12, 31, 31, [12, 13, 54, 32]]`, not `[[13,12,31,31,12,13,54,32]]`. Is that just a typo?

Comment: @matt fixed that typo thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use `<<`, use `+`

```
arr = [13,12,31,31]

arr +=  [12,13,54,32]

# arr => [13,12,31,31,12,13,54,32]
```

Comment: Or [`concat`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-concat) to avoid creating a new array.

Answer (score 7):

You should use [`Array#flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten)

```
[[13,12,31,31,12,13,54,32]].flatten # => [13, 12, 31, 31, 12, 13, 54, 32]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options. You could join your arrays using the `+` operator and not have to deal with the outer array. If you have an outer array and want to flatten it, simply call `flatten` on the array. As matt mentioned in the comments above, you can also use `concat`.

```
# Creates a new array
[13,12,31,31] + [12,13,54,32]
=> [13, 12, 31, 31, 12, 13, 54, 32]

# Creates a new array, unless you use flatten!
[13, 12, 31, 31, [12, 13, 54, 32]].flatten
=> [13, 12, 31, 31, 12, 13, 54, 32]

# Modifies the original array
[13,12,31,31].concat([12,13,54,32])
=> [13, 12, 31, 31, 12, 13, 54, 32]
```